# Create Stored Procedure in SSAS Project

Tags: visual-studio, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssas

I need to use Stored Procedure in SSAS service. I have searched a lot on internet, they give me solution as:

I created a Class Library project and add reference of it in SSAS Project. After referencing in assembly while adding Stored Procedure in SSAS Cube's Data Dimension my Class is not available. I reffered this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1844/sql-server-analysis-services-ssas-dimension-security-stored-procedures/)

How can I create stored procedure using SSAS and use it for generating reports.

If anyone has any idea Please let me know.

Comment: can anybody gone through this please help me as it is urgent.

Comment: Have you tried any thing? if yes then please specify which problem you are facing

Comment: i have specified link ,followed the same step as instructed the step where i am getting problem is to create procedure using code